# context processor content not accessed with django 2.1.3

Tags: python, django

I've tried to make some global context the following way, in the pages app created a file `context_processor`

```
from pages.models import Page

def pages(request):
    response = {}
    response['pages'] = Page.objects.filter(visible=True, parent=None)
    return response
```

and in settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                #project context processors
                'pages.context_processors.pages'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

on the homepage view

```
def home(request, template_name="home.html"):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    response_context = {}

    ...

    return render_to_response(template_name, response_context)
```

problem is I can't access the pages data from the context, everything else works fine.
If I do it directly from the views it works.

Comment: Did you add a `'pages'` to the `response_context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, and use a regular dictionary for the context.

```
def home(request, template_name="home.html"):
    context = {}
    ...
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) shortcut was deprecated in Django 2.0 and will be removed in Django 2.2. In earlier versions of Django, you could pass `context_instance=RequestContext(...)` to `render_to_response` if you wanted to use context processors, but this was removed in Django 1.10.

If you're following a tutorial or book that is using `render_to_response` then it is out of date, and I would think about looking for a different resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `RequestContext` when you `render_to_response`, as is specified in the [documentation on `RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext):

> (...) The second difference is that it automatically populates the context with a few variables, according to the engine’s context_processors configuration option.

```
def home(request, template_name="home.html"):
    response_context = {}

    # ...

    return render_to_response(template_name, response_context, RequestContext(request))
```

But since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) `render_to_response` is deprecated, and thus will be removed in [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2).

One typically uses [**`render`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut:

```
def home(request, template_name="home.html"):
    response_context = {}

    # ...

    return render(request, template_name, response_context)
```

Comment: Using `RequestContext` in `render_to_response` like that will give a `TypeError`